# Why is this not showing the linked question on the side?

Tags: bug, specific-question, hyperlinks

On this question, [The Vowel Eater II](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/40868/the-vowel-eater-ii) , @msh210 links to [The Vowel Eater](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/40829/the-vowel-eater). However, neither question is showing a linked question on the side. Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the source of TVE II, it's linked as `/q/40829` rather than the full question URL. That must be what causes it.

Comment: From the main meta: [Relative links are ignored by “Linked Questions”](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/120678)